# How do I kill lagomorphs for the Monster Hunter achievement?

Tags: achievements, sword-and-sworcery

The achievement **Monster Hunter** reads "Find & somehow slay at least 7 lagomorphs, you jerk", *Lagomorpha* being the order the hare and rabbit family (*Leporidae*, if anyone cares) belongs to. So, it's pretty clear you need to kill the innocent rabbits that are hopping around.

The finding part I seem to have gotten down, as I have found 2 rabbits hopping around outside what appears to be my cabin.

[image: rabbit 1]
[image: rabbit 2]

The slaying part is thus far not going so well. Every time I get close to the rabbits they hop away into the brush. I've tried walking to the location they jumped in and using my sword in the hopes that I would get a lucky hit in or something, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

This is, like the screenshots show, just outside the cabin with the "Home is where the hearth is" sign, where you meet Logfella for the first time. Am I just too early in the game at this point? I've spent like 10 minutes running about trying to kill them, but this is the first time I've played, so I'm wondering if I just don't have the skills I need to be able to kill these things yet. Because of the very low number you need to kill, I'm worried that missing these two will make it more difficult to complete if they are scarce.

How can I murder these elusive lagomorphs?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/superbrothers-sword-sworcery-ep/7065/moar-and-monster-hunter-spoilers/543481/), "**In sworcery mode left click and hold down on a lagomorph for a few seconds and it should explode**"

According to [this video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAq291TsEUE), you don't need to go anywhere new to find the lagomorphs that you need to kill. **The two lagomorphs you indicated are all that need to be found in order to complete this achievement as they can be respawned by leaving and returning to the area.** The process is very simple:

1. Kill both lagomorphs.
2. Exit to another screen and return to see the bunnies respawned.
3. Kill both lagomorphs. You will get a message after the first.
4. Exit to another screen and return to see the bunnies respawned.
5. Kill both lagomorphs.
6. Exit to another screen and return to see the bunnies respawned.
7. Kill one more lagomorph. You will get a message.
8. You could try waiting and see if it pops, but in the video guide, although the poster was unsure if it is needed, they exited to the main menu and that's when the achievement appeared for them so it may be necessary to exit to the main menu once the killing is complete.

Comment: There are rabbits on the other side of the world.

Comment: @wok Yes, there are, but that wasn't the question. The question was how FAE could kill them, whether FAE was too early to get the achievement and whether FAE could deal with the scarcity of these bunnies. I could not find a comprehensive list of all their locations and I know they are all over the world, but FAE didn't ask for someone to list all their locations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your magic thingy by holding on the rabbits. They stand up, transfixed, and eventually pop.