# Are sword and sworcery achievements available for iPhone?

Tags: sword-and-sworcery

Based on this question: [How do I kill lagomorphs for the Monster Hunter achievement?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63551/how-do-i-kill-lagomorphs-for-the-monster-hunter-achievement), there are achievements available for S&S. Is this a steam exclusive? Which platforms are they available for?

If they are not currently available for iOS, is there any news of plans for an update to include these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's definitely no GameCenter entry for sword and sworcery, so no GameCenter achievements. There's no Open Feint or other in-game achievements at all. They're probably something they added to the Steam version as it's expected I guess.

Comment: You're correct, there's no OpenFeint integration either.

Comment: Accepted as answer on April 30th 2012, hopefully there'll be an iPhone update soon.

Comment: @StuperUser if there is I can update, since I own it